# Passing data along with a Matlab function handle

Tags: matlab

```
for i = 2:6
    exp.pico_list(i).config(@configSlave,0); % 0 indicates non-terminal slave node
end
```

The above code doesn't work in Matlab. It complains that I'm passing too many input arguments to exp.pico_list(i).config, which is true. Config only expects a function handle. However, the function configSlave has two arguments. The first is provided by the config function, while the second is a constant (in this case, 0). What is the syntax for passing the zero along with the function handle?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a function handle that takes one input for a function that would normally take two, then you use an anonymous function:

```
fh = @(x)configSlave(x,0)
```

Now `fh` is a handle to a function that takes one input argument. This argument will be used as the first argument for `configSlave`, while the second argument to `configSlave` is fixed to zero.